# Density of a Lebesgue measurable set with $m(E)>0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a Lebesgue measurable set with $m(E)>0$. Prove that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $(-\delta,\delta)\subset E-E:=\{x-y|x,y\in E\}$.

---

Intuitively $m(E)>0$ means that $E$ is dense somewhere on the real line. What we need to prove is exactly a depiction of this kind of density. However, it seems tough for me to give a rigid proof and find the exact $\delta$. I don't know there to get start with. I wonder if anyone can help. Thank you in adcvance!

Comment: This is Theorem B, p. 68 of Measure Theory by P. Halmos.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks! I've checked it out.

Comment: One starting point is to prove that $x \mapsto m(E \cap (E+x))$ is continuous

Comment: Using the $\sigma$-finiteness of $\Bbb R$, we deduce the case for $m(E)<\infty$. Then note that as following by @GEdgar 's comment you have a convolution of two $L^2$ functions thus it is continuous. Then if you get a continuous function $:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, you know what to use to get hold of some $\delta$, right?

Comment: To prove $x \mapsto m(E \cap (E+x))$ is continuous, start first with $E$ an interval, then a finite union of intervals, then approximate the general E with that.